# What's the advantage of creating new orgs in bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I realize the general compartmentalization of apps & services into spaces so you can control access and such.

But I am not clear on why there is also the concept of organization? Are usage charges done per org? Or is it just a way to organize spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organizations are the concept to manage resources and, well, organize work. The [Cloud Foundry docs say about an organization](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html#orgs):

> An org is a development account that an individual or multiple
>   collaborators can own and use. All collaborators access an org with
>   user accounts. Collaborators in an org share a resource quota plan,
>   applications, services availability, and custom domains.

As you said, spaces are used to deploy resources and to control access. Adding another org would make sense to introduce another department, project or maybe even a business unit to a Cloud Foundry instance like the IBM Cloud with Bluemix. Who is accountable (for the deployed resources)? How are projects and teams organized?

Comment: Thanks. Is billing also compartmentalized by organization? In other words DOes one get a breakdown of resource usage and billing per organization?

Comment: There is even a billing role in an org.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - an organization helps segregate different development efforts, similar to the way a space works.  However, when you look at your usage and your bill you can see it broken out by organization.  It's one of the reasons I suggest doing different organizations for different cost centers in an organization - so you can do chargebacks.  See https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/ibm-cloud-bluemix-watson-new-customers/...

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Foundry, Organizations are top level management which consists of multiple spaces. Spaces is like specific team or you can consider as different environments like development, testing, pre-prod or prod. There are multiple roles both in Organization and Space.

For Organization, there are Org Manager and Org Auditor.
Org Manager will look invite users to organization, view quotas and assign quotas to spaces. Org Auditor can check how many users in an org, spaces, quotas details but they can't edit or make change in an organization.

I recommend to have a look at this link https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html#orgs